# Non-shortcircuting boolean operators and C# 7 Pattern matching

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Im currently writing an C# application, targeting .NET 4.7 (C# 7). I am confused after I tried using the new way of declaring a variable utilizing the "is" keyword:
    `if (variable is MyClass classInstance)`
This way it works, but when doing:

```
if (true & variable is MyClass classInstance)
{
    var a = classInstance;
}
```

Visual Studio (I'm using 2017) shows me the the Error `Use of unassigned local variable 'classInstance'`. Using the short-circuting version of `&` (`&&`) it works fine. Am I missing something about the `&` operator? (I know using the shortcircuting versions are much more commonly used, but at this point I'm just curious)

Comment: `&` is a bitwise _and_. It has nothing to do with logical _and_ `&&`.

Comment: This is the first time I'm hearing `&` is used in place of `&&`.

Comment: Still: Why does the error shows up if there is no way that the right side would not be evaluated?

Comment: @Dmitry: that's what I thought too, but it's not right. `&` accepts boolean operators and is a boolean operator in that case, per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator). `&` is *also* a bitwise operator, when applied to integral operators.

Comment: `is` checks type and you specified type and variable name (why?). Remove `classInstance`. Your sample is really confusing. Why do you have `true` there, why do you use `&` instead of  `&&`, why do you specify variable with type instead of type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right indeed.

Comment: @FCin Without the `true`, no boolean operator is needed. I needed to add something, and true would make the most sense for me when trying to create a simple example. Lookup "Pattern matching" in C# 7 please.

Comment: This looks like a plain old bug in the compiler. The following compiles correctly without warning about uninitialized values: `int x; if (true & (x = 1) == 1) { Console.WriteLine(x); }; Console.WriteLine(x);`. Same if `true` is replaced by `foo()`, where `foo()` returns a `bool`. Using `&&` in that case will give an "uninitialized" on the second `Console.WriteLine(x);` (as it should).

Comment: OP- Do you declare a variable named `classInstance` outside the if block, either locally or as a field?

Comment: @JohnWu No, first time use in this scope.

Comment: The & operator always requires both operands to be evaluated.   There is no shortcut for *true* built into the compiler, eliminating dead code is the job of the jitter optimizer.

Comment: @HansPassant Thats the point: The right side has to be evaluated, in every case. It still shows the error.

Comment: I am going with @JeroenMostert if nothing new is being brought up

Comment: @pm100 Look at what Jeroen Mostert allready said: Its too defined as the boolean operator AND in the official C# docs, so its a valid way to use it.

Comment: What is the type of `variable`? Is it actually a `MyClass`?

Comment: @JohnWu Yes, or a subclass. Anything that can be assigned as a MyClass. (In my acutal code `variable` is an instance of a class that implements an Interface. MyClass inherits the same interface)

Comment: @pm100: not *only* is `&` a boolean operator -- `&&` is *defined* in terms of `&` in the standard. I'm wondering if it's not worth writing up a question and an answer just to clarify this, based on how many programmers (including me) don't (didn't) realize how C# deviates from other C-like languages here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - wow i learned something new there. So why does OP get error with & but not &&, both should work

Answer (score 11):

This one hurt my head, but I think I have got it figured out.

This confusion is caused by two quirks: the way the `is` operation leaves the variable undeclared (not null), and the way the compiler optimizes away Boolean, but not bitwise, operations.

**Quirk 1. If the cast fails, the variable is unassigned (not null)**

Per the [documentation for the new `is` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is):

> If exp is true and is is used with an if statement, *varname is assigned* and has local scope within the if statement only.

If you read between the lines, this means that if the `is` cast fails, the variable is considered **unassigned**. This may be counterintuitive (some might expect it to be `null` instead). This means that any code within the `if` block that relies on the variable will not compile if there is ***any*** chance the overall `if` clause could evaluate to `true` without a type match present. So for example

This compiles:

```
if (instance is MyClass y)
{
    var x = y;
}
```

And this compiles:

```
if (true && instance is MyClass y)
{
    var x = y;
}
```

But this does not:

```
void Test(bool f)
{
    if (f && instance is MyClass y)
    {
        var x = y;  //Error: Use of unassigned local variable
    }
}
```

**Quirk 2.  Boolean operations are optimized away, binary ones are not**

When the compiler detects a predestined Boolean result, the compiler will not emit unreachable code, and skips certain validations as a result. For example:

This compiles:

```
void Test(bool f)
{
    object neverAssigned;
    if (false && f)
    {
        var x = neverAssigned;  //OK (never executes)
    }
}
```

But if you use `&` instead of `&&`, it does not compile:

```
void Test(bool f)
{
    object neverAssigned;
    if (false & f)
    {
        var x = neverAssigned;  //Error: Use of unassigned local variable
    }
}
```

When the compiler sees something like `true &&` it just ignores it completely.  Thus

```
    if (true && instance is MyClass y)
```

Is exactly the same as

```
    if (instance is MyClass y)
```

But this

```
    if (true & instance is MyClass y)
```

Is NOT the same. The compiler still needs to emit code that performs the `&` operation and uses its output in a conditional statement. Or even if it doesn't, the current C# 7 compiler apparently performs the same validations as if it were. This may seem a little strange, but bear in mind that when you use `&` instead of `&&`, there is a guarantee that the `&` must execute, and though it seems unimportant in this example, the general case must allow for additional complexifying factors, such as operator overloading.

**How the quirks combine**

In the last example, the result of the `if` clause is determined at run time, not compile time. So the compiler can't be certain that `y` will end up being assigned before the contents of the `if` block are executed. Thus you get

```
    if (true & instance is MyClass y)
    {
        var x = y; //Error: use of unassigned local variable
    }
```

**TLDR**

In the situation of a compound logical operation, c# can't be sure that the overall `if` condition will resolve to true if and only if the cast is successful. Absent that certainty, it can't allow access to the variable, since it might be unassigned. An exception is made when the expression can be reduced to non-compound operation at compile time, for example by removing `true &&`.

**Workaround**

I think the way we are meant to use the new `is` syntax is as a single condition with an `if` clause. Adding `true &&` at the beginning works because the compiler simply removes it. But anything else combined with the new syntax creates ambiguity about whether the new variable will be in an unassigned state when the code block runs, and the compiler can't allow that.

The workaround of course is to nest your conditions instead of combining them:

Won't work:

```
void Test(bool f)
{
    if (f & instance is MyClass y)
    {
        var x = y;  //Error: Use of unassigned local variable
    }
}
```

Works fine:

```
void Test(bool f)
{
    if (f)
    {
        if (instance is MyClass y)
        {
            var x = y;  //Works
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The compiler still needs to emit code that performs the & operation and uses its output in a conditional statement"_ -- says who? With a literal `true`, the compiler is just as free to optimize away the `true &` as it is to optimize away the `true &&`. It seems to me your entire explanation rests on your claim that _"The compiler still needs to emit code that performs the & operation"_, but that claim appears unsubstantiated to me.

Comment: It is substantiated, maybe not irrefutably, by the observed behavior as demonstrated in my numerous code examples. Although perhaps "need" is not the best word-- certainly this behavior is an implementation detail ( a.k.a. "quirk") and a different c# compiler could do what you're suggesting.  (Maybe-- while it is true that `true boolean-and xyz` is always equal to `xyz`, it is not true that `true binary-and xyz` is always equal to `xyz`).

Comment: _"perhaps "need" is not the best word"_ -- it's not even close to the right word. But your use of it presents your supposition as if it _justifies_ the behavior, when in fact all you're doing is _observing_ the behavior. It's not an explanation at all. And we are not dealing with "binary-and", as you put it. The only thing that matters here is the Boolean operator, and there is no such thing as `true binary-and xyz` in C# at all.

Comment: In your last section "Workaround", the code snippet you marked with `Won't work` works on my side. Did you meant to use `&` instead of `&&`?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the rules on definite assignment, which have a special case for `&&`, but *don't* have a special case for `&`. I believe it's working as *intended* by the C# design team, but that the specification may have a little bit more work to do, at least in terms of clarity.

From the ECMA C# 5 standard, section 5.3.3.24:

> For an expression expr of the form `expr-first && expr-second`:
>
> ...
>
> The definite assignment state of v after expr is determined by:
>
> - If expr-first is a constant expression with the value false, then the definite assignment state of v after expr is the same as the definite assignment state of v after expr-first.
> - Otherwise, if the state of v after expr-first is definitely assigned, then the state of v after expr is definitely assigned.
> - Otherwise, if the state of v after expr-second is definitely assigned, and the state of v after expr-first is “definitely assigned after false expression”, then the state of v after expr is definitely assigned.
> - **Otherwise, if the state of v after expr-second is definitely assigned or “definitely assigned after true expression”, then the state of v after expr is “definitely assigned after true expression”.**
> - ...

The relevant part for this case is the one I've highlighted in bold. `classInstance` is "definitely assigned after true expression" with the pattern (`expr-second` above), and none of the earlier cases apply, so the overall state at the end of the condition is "definitely assigned after true expression". That means within the `if` statement body, it's definitely assigned.

There's no equivalent clause for the `&` operator. While there potentially could be, it would be complicated by the types involved - it would have to only apply to the `&` operator when used with `bool` expressions, and I don't *think* most of the rest of definite assignment deals with types in that way.

Note that you don't need to use pattern matching to see this.

Consider the following program:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool a = false;
        bool x;
        bool y = true;
        
        if (true & (y && (x = a)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

The expression `y && (x = a)` is another one where `x` ends up being "definitely assigned after true expression". Again, the code above fails to compile due to `x` not being definitely assigned, whereas if you change the `&` to `&&` it compiles. So at least this isn't an issue in pattern matching itself.

What confuses me somewhat is why `x` isn't still "definitely assigned after true expression" due to 5.3.3.21 ("5.3.3.21 General rules for expressions with embedded expressions"), which contains:

> - The definite assignment state of v at the end of expr is the same as the definite assignment state at the end of expr<sub>n</sub>.

I suspect this is meant to only include "definitely assigned" or "not definitely assigned", rather than including the "definitely assigned after true expression" part - although it's not as clear as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something about the & operator?

No, I don't think so. Your expectations seem correct to me. Consider this alternative example, which does compile without error:

```
object variable = null;
MyClass classInstance;

if (true & ((classInstance = variable as MyClass) != null))
{
    var a = classInstance;
}

var b = classInstance;
```

(To me, it's more interesting to consider the assignment *outside* the `if` body, since that's where the short-circuiting would affect behavior.)

With the explicit assignment, the compiler recognizes `classInstance` as definitely assigned, in the assignments of both `a` and `b`. It should be able to do the same thing with the new syntax.

With logical `and`, short-circuiting or not shouldn't matter. Your first value is `true`, so the second half should always need to be evaluated to get the whole expression. As you've noted, the compiler *does* treat the `&` and `&&` differently though, which is unexpected.

A variation on this is this code:

```
static void M3()
{
    object variable = null;

    if (true | variable is MyClass classInstance)
    {
        var a = classInstance;
    }
}
```

The compiler correctly identifies `classInstance` as not definitely assigned when `||` is used, but has the same apparent misbehavior with `|` (i.e. also saying that `classInstance` is not definitely assigned), even though with the non-short-circuiting operator, the assignment must happen regardless.

Again, the above works correctly with the assignment is explicit, rather than using the new syntax.

If this were *just* about the definite assignment rules not being addressed with the new syntax, then I would expect `&&` to be as broken as `&`. But it's not. The compiler handles that correctly. And indeed, in [the feature documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/patterns.md) (I hesitate to say "specification", because there's no ECMA-ratified C# 7 specification yet), it reads:

> The type_pattern both tests that an expression is of a given type and casts it to that type if the test succeeds. This introduces a local variable of the given type named by the given identifier. **That local variable is definitely assigned when the result of the pattern-matching operation is true.** *[emphasis mine]*

Since short-circuiting produces correct behavior without pattern matching, and since pattern matching produces correct behavior without short-circuiting (and definite-assignment is explicitly addressed in the feature description), I would say this is straight-up a compiler bug. There's probably some overlooked interaction between non-short-circuiting Boolean operators and the way the pattern-matched expression is evaluated that causes the definite assignment to get lost in the shuffle.

You should consider reporting it to the authorities. I think these days, the [Roslyn GitHub issue-tracking](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) is where they track this sort of thing. It might help if you explain in your report how you found this and why that particular syntax is important in your scenario (since in the code you posted, the `&&` operator works equivalently…the non-short-circuiting `&` doesn't seem to confer any advantage to the code).

Comment: I don't believe this is a bug - I believe it's simply that definite assignment rules don't handle `&` in the same way that they handle `&&`. See my answer for details. To prove it's a bug, you'd have to show that the definite assignment rules should make the result of that whole expression "definitely assigned after true expression", and I don't believe they do.

Comment: Currently reconsidering actually - I need to look closer. Not quite deleting my answer yet, but may do so by the time you see this comment.