# Inline variable declaration doesn't compile when using '== false' instead of negation operator

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Consider the following snippets:

```
void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ComboBox comboBox)) return;
    comboBox.DropDownWidth = 100;
}
```

compared to

```
void Bar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender is ComboBox comboBox) == false) return;
    comboBox.DropDownWidth = 100;
}
```

Code including `Foo()` successfully compiles in .Net 4.6.1, while code including `Bar()` results in `Use of unassigned local variable 'comboBox'`.

Without getting into a debate over the reasons behind using `== false` instead of the negation operator, can someone explain why one compiles and the other does not?

Comment: Side note. It's framework agnostic. Rather it's a language feature not related to a .net framework version.

Comment: Try comparing IL after removing the assignment in the Bar with a constant

Comment: I always thought that the syntax was `variableName is TypeName`, but you seem to have `variableName is TypeName otherVariableName`. Is this some new c# feature that I don't know or is it incorrect code? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @spender C# 7 pattern matching.

Comment: Hazarding a guess, it's to stop people from doing crazy things like `if ((sender is ComboBox comboBox) == comboBox.DropDownWidth < 100)`, whereas `if((sender is ComboBox comboBox) && comboBox.DropDownWidth < 100)` is valid.

Comment: @JonathonChase fascinating. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, consider `if((sender is ComboBox comboBox) == !(sender is TextBox textBox))`. Which local would be valid? There's no real way to know at compile time.

Comment: This is a good question. I don't see any mention of this behavior in the [Pattern matching with 'is'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) documentation. It seems like as soon as you do a comparison with the result of `is`, you lose the assignment.

Comment: It does look like a bug to me, I would be tempted to raise an issue on the [Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang).

Comment: *actually you *don't* lose the assignment. At runtime the variable is assigned. It seems that somehow the evaluation of the comparison hides the assignment from the compiler.

Comment: @RufusL How did you get to runtime? I can't get the Bar version to compile.

Comment: @MichaelMinton I modified it slightly and set a breakpoint at the `if` statement: `static void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool result = sender is ComboBox comboBox;

            if (result)
            {
                // Won't compile with the following line:
                // comboBox.DropDownWidth = 100;
            }
        }` At the breakpoint, I can see in the Locals Immediate windows an object named `comboBox` that's identical to `sender` (and `result` is `true`). So accessing the result of the `is` statement breaks the pattern matching.

Comment: For a similar problem, check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866739/non-shortcircuting-boolean-operators-and-c-sharp-7-pattern-matching). Not quite the same though.

Comment: According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching: "Language rules for pattern matching expressions help you avoid misusing the results of a match expression. In the example above, the variables s, c, and r are only in scope and definitely assigned when the respective pattern match expressions have true results. If you try to use either variable in another location, your code generates compiler errors." So I suspect that while it's willing to detect the special case ! and flip the if and (effective) else branches, it's not willing to parse every possible expression.

Comment: This does seem strange. Filed https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer** Thanks to [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172315/julien-couvreur) opening a GitHub issue.

See Neal Gafter's response (copied here from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25788#issuecomment-376955179)):

> However, the error you're seeing is not about scope. It is about
>   definite assignment. A pattern variable is definitely assigned when
>   the pattern-matching expression is true. The unary ! operator reverses
>   assigned-when-true and assigned-when-false. However, the boolean
>   equality operator == throws away the distinction between
>   assigned-when-true and assigned-when-false.

---

I believe the `comboBox` variable will only be created **if the pattern matches**.